# Disable a tab in dijit.layout.tabcontainer

Tags: tabs, dojo, tabcontainer, dijit.layout

```
   alert(dijit.byId("CPane1AvailableContentPane").get("disabled"));
   dijit.byId("CPane1AvailableContentPane").setAttribute("disabled",true);
   alert(dijit.byId("CPane1AvailableContentPane").get("disabled"));
```

- I have a programmatically created dijit.layout.tabcontainer with some tabs.
- Those tabs have programmatically created dijit.contentpane.
- I want to disable a particular tab.
- I tried the above code. but its not working.
- In first alert, its false and in second its true. I hope the value is getting set. but no changes in UI.

> Tabcontainer ID: dijit.byId('tab1');

Is above the only way to disable, or any other method is there?

Answer (score 1):

[DISABLE DOJO TAB](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/layout/TabContainer#disabling-tabs)

--> pane.set("disabled", true);

==> registry.byId('tab1').set('disabled', true);

try this  dijit.byId("CPane1AvailableContentPane").set('disabled',true);